# Approach to move file from s3 to s3 glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I need to create a python flask application that moves a file from s3 storage to s3 glacier. I cannot use the lifetime policy to do this as I need to use glacier vault lock which isn't possible with the lifetime policy method since I won't be able to use any glacier features on those files. The files will be multiple GBs in size so I need to download these files and then upload them on glacier. I was thinking of adding a script on ec2 that will be triggered by flask and will start downloading and uploading files to glacier. 
This is the only solution I have come up with and it doesn't seem very efficient but I'm not sure. I am pretty new to AWS so any tips or thoughts will be appreciated.

Not posting any code as I don't really have a problem with the coding, just the approach I should take.

Comment: Could you trigger programmatically and use Lambda to put S3 files to Glacier via API? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/vault-operations.html

Comment: I have to download the file from s3 and then upload it to glacier. I can't directly archive from s3 since I need the files in proper glacier format. Also a lambda runs for 15 minutes at most as far as I know. That won't be enough time to download and then upload the file as it's size will be multiple GBs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your requirement is to use **Glacier Vault Lock** on some objects to guarantee that they cannot be deleted within a certain timeframe.

Fortunately, similar capabilities have recently been added to Amazon S3, called [Amazon S3 Object Lock](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/s3-object-lock/). This works at the object or bucket level.

Therefore, you could simply use **Object Lock** instead of moving the objects to Glacier.

If the objects will be infrequently accessed, you might also want to change the Storage Class to something cheaper before locking it.

See: [Introduction to Amazon S3 Object Lock - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lock.html)

Comment: Our main reason for using glacier was because it was Finra compliant. I don't think s3 did.

Comment: As per the first link: "S3 Object Lock has been assessed for SEC Rule 17a-4(f), FINRA Rule 4511, and CFTC Regulation 1.31 by Cohasset Associates."